# OnSelect equivalent for <option>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<select>` tag and I want it to change the value of a hidden input when an option is selected.
What I thought was to use this:

```
<input type=hidden value=Ineedtochangethis name=asdf>
<select><option onselect="stuff()">Option 1 is selected</option>...</select>
```

And then this

```
function stuff() {
document.getElementsByName("asdf").value=opt1slct;
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work. What can I do to get a similar effect?

Comment: This possibly doesn't work because you are getting an array of elements - then treating it as though it's a single element. Have you tried giving it an id instead and using `getElementById`?

Comment: It actually doesn't work because there is no text selected when you change options. What I want to know if there's any similar way that actually makes this happen.

Comment: It is a basic but good question and confuses many at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `selectedIndex` property (and potentially the `options` one as well) of your `select` element.

```
<input id="yourHiddenField" type="hidden"/>
<select onchange="stuff(this);">
  <option>Option 1 is selected</option>
</select>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function stuff(yourSelectElement){
  document.getElementById('yourHiddenField').value = yourSelectElement.options[yourSelectElement.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}
```

And if you want to store just one number in your hidden field, use the `value` attribute on your `option` tags like so:

```
<option value="1">Option 1 is selected</option>
```

Then the JS changes like this:

```
document.getElementById('yourHiddenField').value = yourSelectElement.options[yourSelectElement.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: But I don't want to make the value equal to the option's inner HTML. I want it to be a number, and the option is going to be a text string.

Comment: You have not specified this in your question. Use the `value` attribute on your `option` tags and replace `innerHTML` with `value` then. The `value` attribute holds your number.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the java syntax of that, I'm not really good at java. (Mainly the  yourSelectElement.options[yourSelectElement.selectedIndex] part)

Comment: The language you are writing in is called **JavaScript**, not Java. The code that you have difficulty with is a beautiful marriage between [HTMLSelectElement.prototype.options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex and the [Property Accessor (Index) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 2):

```
please check following code:  
  <select onChange="jsFunction()" id="selectOpt">
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    function jsFunction(){
      var myselect = document.getElementById("selectOpt");
      if(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value == 1){
          alert('hide');
      }else{
           alert('show');
      }
    }
```

Comment: yes.. that is correct way to get selected element using javascript.